# Hive Query Taking too long to execute

Tags: hive, hiveql, bigdata

I am running HIVE on my local system using VM player. I have dedicated 12 GB to virtual machine and rest 4 GB for system work. I tried to fetch the list of DB in HIVE and it took around 63 sec to give result. Then I tried creating a table with 4 columns and it neither gave me success or failure as result. Can you help me with it?

Comment: post your query and error you are getting

Comment: I am not getting any error. The screen stays as it is post pressing enter. There is no success/Failure output.

Answer (score -1):

12GB memory is sufficient to execute create table command. Please restart the hive and try creating table again after selecting or creating a database. 
Please check if your query is as correct. And

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( eid int, name String, salary String, destination String) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’;

It would be helpful if you can post the query you are using.

Comment: I restarted HIVE, ran the query on different terminal and the output is same. The screen got freezed! No success/Failure. My query is similar to yours with just 2 columns in a table, it's just the basic query to create a Table.

Answer (score -1):

There should be no problem with the space allocated , since 12 GB is pretty much sufficient, to execute Hive.

To know whether the table creation is success or failure, you can do one of the following:

In the hive terminal use one the commands below:

a)`set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir`;
b)`describe formatted <table_name>`;
c)`show create table <table_name>`

The `hive-default.xml` or the  `hive-site.xml` has the `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property.

Generally it is `/usr/hive/warehouse`.

These will show where the hive data is stored.

Check if the appropriate folder is created along with its content.

The success or failure can be checked this way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you please mention why the answer is downvoted?

Comment: thanks keshav for reply, I ran first condition. But I can't run the second one coz the table is yet to be created in HIVE. It's is not processing a simple Create table query. The services were up and running!

Comment: Did you check if any folder is getting created in the warehouse directory?